# Unique .exe file in visual Studio, C# desktop application

Tags: visual-studio

I have C# desktop application created in Visual Studio.

I need to have one executable file, which I can run anywhere. Without compiler or need of having folders of libraries. The `.exe` file I have in project folder doesn't work alone.

Thanks

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: Hah, How to do that? How to create one executable file, to send it anywhere and open it anywhere having just one file

Comment: If you create a C# program with Visual Studio, it *depends* on the .NET framework. That .NET framework (the right version of it) **must be installed** on any computer you want to run your application on. No way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Create installable file using any third party software i.e Advance Installer to send your project anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `.NET` application executable then YES you can send it anywhere and run it anywhere having just one file; provided the fact that wherever or whichever machine you are trying to run it; have `.NET Framework` installed.

Else, you should create a self extracting installer which will not only include the executable but also will have the framework executable. That way wherever you run the installer will first install the framework and then you can run your `exe` without any trouble.